# Firebase console doesn't load list of users

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

I am using fireAuth for my flutter project.
But since the latest update of the plugin (0.6.2+1), the firebase console generate an unknown error when I try to refresh the website.[image]

In english, the error is " an unknown error has been generated during users loading."

Comment: A common cause of problems in the Firebase console is by plugins/extensions from your browser. Try using the console in an incognito window or after disabling all browser extensions/plugins. If that doesn't help, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I restart my browser and it works.